# Bulk insert efficiency for inserting a list with one row

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, bulkinsert, sqlbulkcopy

I'm attemping to use bulk insert and replace it with current common insertion in my project. Some of insertion requests (BillType.Booklet) are a list with one row and others are a list with multiple row.

```
   public async Task CreateBill(List<BillReceiverDto> Receivers, BillType BillType)
    {
       
       var bulkList =new List<BillReceiverDto>();

        if (BillType == BillType.Booklet)
        {
            bulkList.Add(Receivers.FirstOrDefault());
        }
        else
        {
            bulkList.AddRange(Receivers);
        }

        await _dbContextProvider.GetDbContext().BulkInsertAsync(bulkList);
    }
```

Bulk insert have a great performance for inserting huge data, specially more than 100. It insert 5,000 entities in 75 millisecond. But Is it efficient to use bulk insert a list with one row? Is there any drawbacks such as overhead or etc...?

Comment: I do not think so.  Bulk copy just does the copy and ignore the types.  If the types od not match you will get an exception.  An Insert will try to convert types which actually may take longer.

Comment: The problem is not ability to convert. question is about the efficiency of Bulk insert a list with one row.

Comment: One word: benchmark.

Comment: [Mandatory reading](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/). First establish if a difference would even matter, long before asking random strangers on the internet if there's a difference. Then establish results yourself. If there are then still questions left it's another matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I'm the owner of [Entity Framework Extensions](http://entityframework-extensions.net/)

It depends on the library you are using Aref Hemati,

In our library, if there are 10 entities or less to insert, we directly use a SQL statement. So the `SqlBulkCopy` overhead is not used.

So using our library even with one row is fine but obviously optimized for hundreds and thousands of rows.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the BulkInsertAsync extension uses SqlBulkCopy under the hood. In which case, I blogged some benchmarks not that long ago, that might be useful.

While I didn't focus on single row inserts, there did seem to be a cost when using SqlBulkCopy for lower numbers of rows (100) versus Table Valued Parameter approach. As the volumes ramp up, SqlBulkCopy pulls away for performance but there was a noticeable overhead for low volume. How much of an overhead? In the grand scheme of things you're probably not going to notice 10s of milliseconds.

If you're dealing with up to hundreds of rows, I'd actually recommend a Table Valued Parameter approach for performance. Larger volumes - SqlBulkCopy.

Depending on your needs/views on overheads here, I'd be tempted to check how many rows you have to insert and use the mechanism that best fits the volume. Personally, I wouldn't use SqlBulkCopy for low numbers of rows if that is a very typical scenario, because of the overhead.

Blog:
https://www.sentryone.com/blog/sqlbulkcopy-vs-table-valued-parameters-bulk-loading-data-into-sql-server

Comment: Three remarks. 1) Your test harness doesn't account for startup/warmup overhead which may become significant for small loads even at multiple runs; consider randomizing scenario order. 2) Using `DataTable` is itself a very inefficient way to feed the mechanism for larger loads; an `IEnumerable<SqlDataRecord>` is more work, but also noticeably faster. This doesn't invalidate the test, just good to know in general. 3) If literally a single row is inserted all or most of the time (the OP's scenario), using a simple parameterized `INSERT` is likely faster than either bulk copy *or* TVP.

Comment: A lot went into trying to excluding overhead costs that falls outside the scope of the actual data loading process mechanism as opposed to external overhead - from initializing the db data/log files, to excluding the cost of generating the test data (so it's all done in-memory up front, hence DataTable), to running the tests many times in many different orders. So I think that side is good and inline with MS docs on what to expect from SqlBulkCopy overhead-wise.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, I there any documentation that says Insert is faster?  I suspect the bulk copy is faster.  The Insert in the drive can do type conversion while the bulk copy doesn't to the type conversion.

Comment: A dedicated DataTable vs. IDataReader/DbDataReader comparison would be interesting - I've done a few others on SqlBulkCopy, but this is still on my TODO list. Certainly streaming data into a destination db is useful esp with large volumes/memory limitations. 
On the single insert side - absolutely. In general, I'd go: single inserts for very low numbers -> TVP for up to 1000s (subject to testing exact scenario) -> SqlBulkCopy

Comment: @jdweng: why would you need or trust docs here? Benchmarking is key. There is no reason to assume type conversions are the only (or even the most important) thing that would influence performance, and for production use we may assume no type conversions are taking place anyway, as presumably you can tune for that.

Comment: @AdaTheDev: If you did run the tests many times in different orders, that's not reflected in your code, which is why I mentioned it (`TestScenarioRunner` always applies the same order). Anything you do outside of the benchmark code is good to mention, but reduces the usefulness for others, as they must remember to do the same for an apples-to-apples comparison. The other stuff you mention is fine, which is why I didn't mention it. :-) But JIT/GC/initialization overhead especially can be an unexpectedly large source of delays for some cases, especially for small tests with running time in ms.

Comment: @JeroenMostert : Everybody is just assuming the BulkCopy is faster and it may not.  I really depends on the driver.  I'm not assuming anything.  I just said "Probably".

Comment: @JeroenMostert Yep, that's really just because of trying to produce something that feels most consumable by a wider audience/not having a bit of extra complexity there to do randomization, but manually - yes it was done. I could have been clearer when I said about running the tests several times to check overall consistency of the trends tbh, as I ran them in all sorts of orders to the point my machine was really starting to hate me - hindsight I guess :)